# rails 3 link_to put method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using `link_to` helper and trying to set the method as :put as show in the documentation.  [Link](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

however when i see the method is falling back to get, what am i doing wrong. Here is my syntax

```
<%= link_to "Original One","/users/#{user.id}?params=#{session[:user]}", :remote => true,:method => :put %>
```

Comment: what is the html generated by it?

Comment: <a rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="put" href="/user/618987?ria">Original</a>

Comment: So you are getting `data-method="put"`. What else you want?

Comment: when i click the url i see all the parameters that are sent, earlier in rails 2.3 the parameters were not visible. Can you tell me what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rails 2.3, `link_to` won't work the way you expect it to work like in Rails 4. For Rails 2.3, you can use `button_to`, and pass the same options in it. [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)'s more you can find about it.

```
<%= button_to "Update", "/users/#{@user.id}", :method => :put, :remote => true  %>
```